# Need free-form entry in 'articles & blogs' profile section in Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I have articles I have written in magazines (remember those?) which I would like to reference on "Writing : Articles & Blogs" in my Careers profile.

I don't see any way to do this:  when I hit "add an article or blog post you've written", it demands a URL before it lets me go any further.  Printed magazine articles aren't accessible from URIs; you have to physically walk to a thing called a "library" and find the actual physical magazine without the aid of a URI.  It's terrible, I know.

Short of hosting a PDF of my article online (which I might do as a workaround, depending on copyright issues), there is no way to enter articles and publications that exist in non-URI-addressable resources such as trade journals, print-only specialty publications, etc.